# GCP vpc same destination , different routes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes, google-vpc

Looking to the following architecture, I'm wondering if possible to force default traffic from VPC A to go to NVA-2 on VPC C and entering to NVA-1 in VPC B on its route.

On VPC B, the NVA-1 is a Network Virtual Appliance.
Traffic from VPC A should have NVA-1 as its next hop for default traffic
NVA-1 will then route traffic on OS level and make it out from same interface but this time it should go to the VPC C and with NVA-2 as destination

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Ops in my previous company did that and it worked well. the main problem is the point of failure that you create. But because I'm not an Ops, a Sysadmin or a networkAdmin, I can't tell you what to configure to make this design a reality!

Comment: Although transitive peering is not a supported feature of VPC network peering, your network illustration with intermediate appliances (which perform routing / forwarding ) should work to enable connection from A<->C transiting through B. Also, it is a good practice to have distinct CIDR ranges allocated to respective VPC’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve managed to make it work using a fourth VPC (interco vpc between vpc B and vpc C)
default route is routed on NVA-1 from VPC B to VPC interco
Then VPC interco passes the traffic to vpc C using imported route from peering